# How to output date in this format: Date.UTC(2016,06,06,13,13,13)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I've some data from an AJAX call. One of the parts is date. I need the date to be printed in this format:

```
Date.UTC(YY,MM,DD,hh,mm,ss)
```

I tried this:

```
var jsonDate = field.substr(1, field.indexOf(',')-1);
var phpDate = jsonDate.split(/[- :]/);
var jsDate = new Date(Date.UTC(phpDate[0], phpDate[1]-1, phpDate[2], phpDate[3], phpDate[4], phpDate[5]));
```

But it returns a string and it's in my local time zone.
Something like this:

```
Mon Jul 13 2015 21:11:05 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
```

I need to convert it to the mentioned format.

Comment: You can use `toISOString()` to convert any date to UTC: https://jsfiddle.net/os3a1p7u/

Comment: if it was that urgent, would you be asking a question here ?

Comment: check this http://momentjs.com/ it has related examples maybe useful

Comment: I was searching for the solution Rory suggested. Otherwise, I'd be asking.

Comment: @ArashtadLtd then by all means, accept and upvote his answer !

Comment: No I couldn't find a way to get to what I need with that suggestion.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. Maybe I've described badly. Maybe the whole question is silly or whatever. What I need is a JS date in this format as output: Date.UTC(the date/time here). I can generate it by putting what I already got in a string but that won't work. I need the date in the mentioned format for feeding Highcharts as I've tagged above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use jquery-dateFormat

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

```
var jsDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 1, 23, 13, 14, 15));
var fromated = $.format.date(Date.UTC(2016, 1, 23, 13, 14, 15), "yy,MM,dd,hh,mm,ss");
console.log("Date.UTC(" + fromated + ")"); //Date.UTC(16,02,23,06,44,15)
```

Comment: Can't understand your comment properly! do you want `Date.UTC(2015,06,13,21,11,05)` whole as a string? if yes i have edit my code

Comment: Not as a string, but a JS date format. I need just itself not its output and what it can generate at the client side.

Comment: Thank you Ajesh. I'd tried that before. I thinks it's not a JS problem but something's wrong with Highchart (what I need the data for). Please take a look at the post I wrote below if you got some experience in Highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toISOString()` to convert any date to UTC:

```js
var dt = new Date('Mon Jul 13 2015 21:11:05 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)');
console.log(dt); // for me == Mon Jul 13 2015 17:41:05 GMT+0100 (BST)
console.log(dt.toISOString()) // == UTC
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but it's not the point. I need the output just like Date.UTC(the date/time here). 2015-07-13T16:41:05.000Z or so doesn't solve the matter.

Comment: Please let me explain better. I already got: Mon Jul 13 2015 21:11:05 GMT+0100 (time zone). Now I want to get this output: Date.UTC(2015,06,13,21,11,05) instead. I'm not about displaying the result at the front end. But I need it for using in my codes. Highcharts accepts the format I mentioned and I need that format for feeding Highcarts. Thanks